# React beginner here! How do I launch a react website over FTP?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ftp

I seem to have found nothing on the internet about react and FTP and what I have found is so blurry and hard to understand. Is there anybody who could help me understand how to deploy over FTP?

Comment: [Create a production build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build) and upload the contents of the `build` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a build of the project. In your terminal run `npm run build`. This will create a new folder named "build". The contents of this folder is what you want to upload to FTP.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me a lot of time.